# Unable to implement back button in Actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i am creating a application with `ActionBar`.
in which action bar performing sharing action.
but i want to add the back button along with the sharing implementation.
Basically i want both things to work as per the user selection.

here is my code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

        // Handle item selection
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view); //Unreachable Code
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String fileName = "desi.png";
        File dest = new File(sd, fileName);
        try {
            FileOutputStream out;
            out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item:
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(dest);
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.share)));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

i myself implemented both things but ended with unreachable code as eclipse mentioned to me.
any help will be appreciated. 
Thank You!

Comment: In the first switch, "case" ends with a return and "default" ends with a return too; meaning that whatever the case is, just finish the method and therefore the unreachable code warning.

Comment: so i have to eliminate the default code for the switch case?

Comment: as @yygyt place super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); to the very bottom after default: break; it is working in my case just tried it

Comment: @JaiSharma Roughly skimming over the code, your other switch may suffer from the same problem. It is more logical though, considering the switch block is at the bottom of your method. I'm not saying you can't but most of the time, instead of return, people use "break;" in the switch clauses.

Comment: i think i got it...posting the solved code.

Comment: And there is this other thing. You want to implement your own back button in your action bar, it's OK; but, why don't you want to take the standard approach as in here http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html?

Comment: what if i declare back button activity right after the switch case for sharing?

Comment: done check the edit i resolve the issue
thank you all for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the correct code:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item:
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(dest);
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.share)));
                return true;


            case android.R.id.home:
                // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

i tried to implement both case in single `switch` statement and this removes the error and plus the app is working according to the code.
Thank You!